# Estoy intentando realizar un insert a traves de JAVA usando android studio a la API de Openbravo, pero me da error

Tags: java, android, json, api

estaba intentando insertar datos a Openbravo a traves de la API, usando JAVA desde Android Studio, la cuestión es que me lanza un código 200, es decir, está enviando datos correctamente pero no los está insertando, a continuación muestro el código

```
 public String insertAction (String client, String org, String userid, String txtDocmentno, String user, String pass) throws Exception {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("client", "660C92DE11AE421D94B3F16E71585683");
        json.put("organization", "2D3304A6337B499EBE030D731F6064F0");
        json.put("active", true);
        json.put("name", "MAHLE ARGENTINA");

        String urlString = "http://10.20.30.150/openbravo/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Brand";

        String authString = "APP-USER" + ":" + "102530055";
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(json.toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Registro insertado correctamente: " + responseCode);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al insertar los datos. Código de respuesta: " + responseCode);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo coloque directamente los datos que quiero insertar como prueba

El resultado es este:

```
I/System.out: Errorjava.lang.RuntimeException: Error al insertar los datos. Código de respuesta: 200
```

Comment: Afirmas que te da error, pero el hecho es que no da error ninguno... está devolviendo un code 200. Eres tú quien tira un error cuando no te devuelve 201. En tu if compruebas que el código de respuesta sea HTTP_CREATED (201), pero claramente está devolviendo OK (200). Cuando trabajas con una API es muy importante leer la documentación para ver qué responde en cada caso... o por lo menos comprobar que la respuesta sea 2xx, y no 201 exactamente. Cualquier 2XX te va a indicar que la llamada ha ido OK.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas creando un error cuando el "response code" es `201` ([HTTP_CREATED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_CREATED)) o cuando es diferente a este valor

```
int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Registro insertado correctamente: " + responseCode);
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error al insertar los datos. Código de respuesta: " + responseCode);
}
```

Esto es incorrecto, ya que se va a generar siempre un error.

**Si tu código de respuesta es `200`, indica un estado de éxito, es decir, que la solicitud se ha realizado correctamente, por lo tanto, en este caso no deberías generar un error.**

Noto que usas la clase `HttpURLConnection`, en este caso si obtienes un código de respuesta 200, puedes definir que la petición fué correcta y puedes obtener esa información por ejemplo para imprimirla,

```
 public String insertAction (String client, String org, String userid, String txtDocmentno, String user, String pass) throws Exception {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("client", "660C92DE11AE421D94B3F16E71585683");
        json.put("organization", "2D3304A6337B499EBE030D731F6064F0");
        json.put("active", true);
        json.put("name", "MAHLE ARGENTINA");

        String urlString = "http://10.20.30.150/openbravo/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Brand";

        String authString = "APP-USER" + ":" + "102530055";
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(json.toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //* Conexión exitosa código 200, petición satisfactoria :-)
             try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                      // Realiza algo con la linea que lee a partir de la respuesta.
                }
             }
        } else {
             //* La petición no fue satisfactoria :-(
        }
        /*--------------------------------------------------------*/

       /*int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Registro insertado correctamente: " + responseCode);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al insertar los datos. Código de respuesta: " + responseCode);
        }*/

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Como conclusión, en este caso:

> "me lanza un código 200, es decir, está enviando datos correctamente
> pero no los está insertando"

Debes revisar el método de tu Web Service ( http://10.20.30.150/openbravo/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/Brand ), ya que con los datos que le envía no esta realizando la operación requerida.

Comment: muchas gracias, es verdad que capaz la respuesta estaba siendo mal analizada, ya lo resolví, y también descubrí que no insertaba ya que debía tener un array extra para poder insertar los datos donde correspondían, así que ya está todo bien Saludos...